# CSS or JS Solution - Bold Parent UL when hovering over child LI in a nav menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I need to bold the text in a UL Parent menu element when hovering over the child element, LI.

I have tried several JS solutions whose syntax is correct, but it does not seem to do anything. I also tried CSS Solutions, but I could not wrap my head around the selectors for such an advanced technique.

**Here is the HTML Structure**:

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();


            var _menu  = $j(this).find('.menu-item-has-children');

            $j(_menu).mouseover(function(){
                _menu.addClass('hb_menu');

            }).mouseout(function(){;
                _menu.removeClass('hb_menu');
            });
});
```

```css
.hb_menu {
 font-weight:bolder;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
<ul class="menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="home">Top-Menu</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu" style="display:none">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Link1</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Link2</a></li>
   </ul></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Every JS solution I tried never seemed to add the class. The no conflict mode part of the solution is because this is being used in a custom Wordpress JS File. I know the script is being properly enqueued in the source, and any syntax errors show immediately in Firebug console.

The menu is being styled with other CSS and JS for formatting and an animated dropdown menu. I haven't included any CSS attempts I made because I am sure they were pure nonsense.

**TO CLARIFY** 
The desired behavior is to style the *parent* element LI (.menu-item-has-children) when the child elements (from .sub-menu) LI are being moused over.

Comment: prior to answer you, can you post or explain `_title` variable.

Comment: The _title var was a typo. I meant to use the var/parameter _menu

Comment: check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rogelio_meza/gem2d2ry/1/. I add a new CSS class for avoid to the children bold. Remember to change the `$` by `jQuery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to bold "Top-Menu" while mouse is over Link1 or Link2, I've made a simple example which shows how to reach that effect:
http://jsfiddle.net/y6eeyr36/

It's mostly basing on your code, but with small differences in looking for node which should be bold

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(".menu-item-has-children").children().mouseover(function(){
    $j(this).parent().parent().find("a").first().addClass('hb_menu');

}).mouseout(function(){;
    $j(this).parent().parent().find("a").first().removeClass('hb_menu');
});
```

Comment: This works very well in JSFiddle, but does not in my production code. It also seems to bold the parent when over just it. To clarify, I am only looking to bold the title when the children elements are mouseover'd.

Comment: After investigation CSS selectors, this solution worked, in addition to jQuery's document ready.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you wrap your code in `$(document).ready()`, so the events are binded to the selectors after the DOM has been loaded. Then, since you care only when hovering the children, we attach the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events only to the sub menu items. Then, we get the parent of the sub menu item, which is the main menu, and we add or remove the `hb_menu` class to the `a` tag.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".sub-menu li").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).parents(".menu-item-has-children").children("a").addClass("hb_menu");
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).parents(".menu-item-has-children").children("a").removeClass("hb_menu");
    });
});
```

Comment: This actually works in my production code. Thanks for reminding me of document ready; however this code styles the children bold - something I feel like I could accomplish with less hoops in CSS. 

I want to style the _parent_ when the children are mouseover'd. For emphasis on the user's location.